# Store Javascript values to SQL Server Database

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to store some javascript variables to sql server database. But when I'm running the code, an alert is displayed saying Internal server error.

```
window.onload = function () 
{ codeLatLng(); SaveUserLocation(); return false }
        /*===========================================================*/
        function SaveUserLocation() {
                //Jquery ajax call to server side method
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //Url is the path of our web method (Page name/function name)
                    url: "FriendHomePage.aspx/SaveFriendLocation",
                    //Pass paramenters to the server side function
                    data: "{'LocationName':'" + userLocationName + "', 'UserID':'" + myUserID + "'}",
                    success: function (response) {
                        //Success or failure message e.g. Record saved or not saved successfully
                        if (response.d == true) {
                            alert("Record saved successfully");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Record could't be saved");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        //Show error message(if occured)
                        alert("Error: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }




[WebMethod]
public static bool SaveFriendLocation(string LocationName, int UserID)
{
    bool status;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FTSCS"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO tblLocation (LocationName,UserID) VALUES (@LocationName,@UserID)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", LocationName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            Int32 retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (retVal > 0)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something has gone wrong in your C# code.

Comment: Not necessarily, could be a configuration issue, with the set-up never allowing making it through to the code-behind execution.

Comment: Could be a million and one issues, but with that little information how can anyone tell?

Comment: Open up your browser developer tools (usually F12 key). Go and inspect the response of your ajax request and then post the full error message.

Comment: My guess would be internal server error means an exception somewhere. But it could be a number of issues. There isn't enough info in your post, you will just get best guesses. Does the debugger in VS break and give you an exception message?

Comment: I got it working. But there another issue now, The field LocationName has an undefined value, When i did a check using alert boxes to test the value of the variable userLocationName, its value becomes undefined after execution of codeLatLng() function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely related to the fact you aren't passing up a valid JSON string i.e. `{ 'property': 'value' }`.

It's recommended you use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (or equivalent) when serializing JSON

```
var data = { LocationName: userLocationName, UserID: myUserID };
...
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Comment: I got it working. But there another issue now, The field LocationName has an undefined value, When i did a check using alert boxes to test the value of the variable userLocationName, its value becomes undefined after execution of codeLatLng() function.

Comment: @programmer008 if you copied my code exactly it wouldn't been wrong as I just noticed that I had it as `Location` rather than `LocationName` - I have updated this. However, the fact that your variables don't have values are a different story, as a test try just hardcoding values in and verify that the approach provided here works.

Comment: Yeah it works. But the value is hard-coded.How to resolve that? The variable userLocationName is a global one. When the function codeLatLng() executes its value must change and yes it changes. But it should contain the last value that was assigned to it. Right? But why is that containing an undefined value?

Comment: @programmer008 that's beyond the scope of the original question, there is no code indicating what `codeLatLng()` does nor where the `userLocationName` variable is actually being set (my guess is it's not getting set anywhere if it's `undefined`).

Comment: userLocationName = results[1].formatted_address;
This is where i'm setting the value of the variable userLocationName. I can't post the whole function definition because of restriction of number of characters.

Comment: @programmer008 it looks like we are now getting into the realm of Google Maps API, this is not what your original problem was. You will need to investigate why `formatted_address` is undefined (e.g. perhaps you are not passing all the relevant parameters). Regardless, this is way beyond the scope of your question and in the interest of actually keep the answer relevant I suggest if you need help you post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in such situations you should turn on debug mode set break point   and find out a **real** problem. If you can't resolve your **real** problem you can post a question here. Your question looks ambiguous because of possible errors:

- webmethod doesn't receive input data
- configuration settings are not valid
- different SQL issues